# Write in "ProgramData" folder (W7 and Vista) .NET

Tags: .net, uac, windows-vista, programdata

I install my app under "Program Files" directory. And I install data, under "ProgramData" directory:

**Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData**

In programData I have created folder to save data. Example:

**C:\ProgramData\MyApp\MyData\here I have files and folders**

Under XP all runs fine. But not under Vista or W7 OS.

I can read files in this directory, but I can not write files, I can not create new files, etc. The user is logged as Admin.

Where I can store data without restrictions? I need store data in a folder visible for all users

**EDITED:**

I have this code in my app.manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- Opciones del manifiesto de Control de cuentas de usuario
             Si desea cambiar el nivel de Control de cuentas de usuario de Windows, reemplace el 
             nodo requestedExecutionLevel por alguno de los siguientes.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            Si desea utilizar la virtualización de archivos y del Registro para la compatibilidad 
            con versiones anteriores, elimine el nodo requestedExecutionLevel.
        -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Comment: Related Post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191941/c-file-write-permission-issue-under-program-files-folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a UAC thing. You have your program run as administrator for creating/deleting files/folders in this SpecialFolder.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand it. 

I can not write nor being an admin user.

And the customers not want disable UAC.

Comment: Well even if you're logged on as administrator you normally don't have all admin privileges. That is the concept of UAC. You do have the same behavior when you want to manually delete a file somewhere in "Program Files". But if you run your application as admin (start with "Run as administrator...) you can delete/create files in that folder. You can also force your application to be running as admin via the manifest file.

Comment: Ok, then, in my app.manifest file, I need to insert  this code "<requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />" instead of "<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />"?

Comment: More like "<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"/>. Also see: http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2007/04/making-your-assembly-run-as.html for example.

Comment: Along with the above comments, I also have set the permission to FullTrust as this:      <applicationRequestMinimum>
        <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="FullTrust" />
        <PermissionSet version="1" ID="FullTrust" Unrestricted="true" />
      </applicationRequestMinimum>

Answer (score 8):

An easy to understand explanation of the different places you can store program data can be found here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/cjacks/archive/2008/02/05/where-should-i-write-program-data-instead-of-program-files.aspx

As regards ProgramData, it says:

> FOLDERID_ProgramData /
>   System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData
>   The user would never want to browse
>   here in Explorer, and settings changed
>   here should affect every user on the
>   machine. The default location is
>   %systemdrive%\ProgramData, which is a
>   hidden folder, on an installation of
>   Windows Vista. You'll want to create
>   your directory and set the ACLs you
>   need at install time.

Comment: About "You'll want to create your directory and set the ACLs you need at install time." How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

it is a conceptual issue at first look:

You should NOT use the "ProgramData" directory but some user specific files. 
Needed installation data should installed in the "program files" or in the registry.