# How to write files in c# as an administrator?

Tags: c#, windows-7, uac

I have c# program which writes an xml file to "C:" disk. I published my program as one click package because it's for test purpose only. But the problem is the one click package doesn't have "run as admin" option. So how can I solve this problem ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct solution is *not* to force administrator elevation to bypass the built-in operating system security.

The correct solution is to *fix* the broken program. Even though it's just a test program, it should be written correctly.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191941/file-write-permission-issue-under-program-files-folder) and the answers for more details. Even though it deals with the `Program Files` folder instead of the root, the underlying problem and solutions are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works with One Click Deployment, but you could try to include an Manifest with your executable to request that the application is run with higher privileges.

See [Create and Embed an Application Manifest (UAC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).