# Create Directory - Access denied

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I try to create a new directory in Program Files for my program I'm thrown an error saying access is denied. This is the error:  `Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\PointOfSales' is denied.` Why's this? I couldn't find any C# specific help that solved my problem. This is the code I'm using now.

```
if (!Directory.Exists("C:\\Program Files\\PointOfSales"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Program Files\\PointOfSales");
        }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know if this is good idea. Give full access to "Everyone" on that folder.

Comment: Can you create the folder manually? Try running your application as an administrator.

Comment: See this post.  You should have your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191941/file-write-permission-issue-under-program-files-folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program running as the current user does not have the permissions to create a directory in the Program Files location.  Some locations require admin privileges (for either the program or the user) to create Directories and other file I/O operations.

If the program won't be allowed to run as admin, have the installer program create the directories for you.  Many user applications won't be allowed to run as admin (as part of company security policies), so creating directories in protected locations won't be possible in those situations.

If you let the installer do it, you can specify `requireAdministrator (/level='requireAdministrator')` in a C++ installer program for `UAC Execution Level` option.

For a C# program you can put the following in your manifest to insure it runs as admin:

```
<security>
  <requestedPrivileges>
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
```

Comment: When building a commercial application, is there around this? Or will it just have to be admins only?

Comment: @Nathan This is how UAC behaves.  If the user has UAC enabled your program will not run as administrator by default.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it figured out now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the App needs to run as Administrator.

Try and add this to the manifest

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```