# Create a program/installation package that needs Admin rights

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, admin

I have created a program in C# with Visual Studio 2008.

I can package it as a .msi file, which installs just fine. However, when installed, for instance, in the Program Files (x86) folder, which is the default, it can't write to the .xml file that's included (using .xml for settings and small storage). It only works when running as Administrator.

My question is, how do you build your Setup and Deployment so that it gets Admin rights automatically instead of needing user compatibility setup?

Comment: The Program Files folder has always been restricted to admins for write/modify. On XP nobody noticed because everyone ran as admin. On UAC systems even admins run limited unless they are elevated with a manifest or explicitly run as admin. You need to decide if your app is for limited users or not, and if it is for limited users then use folders and registry locations they are allowed to create/modify, or give your app an elevation manifest so it demands admin privilege when it starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not recommended by microsoft to place any user files in the programFiles directory, it doesn't belong there.

Instead write those files in the ProgramData folder.

**EDIT:** A fast search found a duplicate question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191941/file-write-permission-issue-under-program-files-folder)