# File access denied in deployment

Tags: .net, logging, file-io, access-denied

I've created a simple Logging class below in C# for my single threaded application. It has 3 self explanatory public methods (Clear(), Log(), and Show()). It works as expected when I'm running the program in development mode. When I deploy and install the program however, I get the following error the first time Log() is called.

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 
Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\programDir\log.txt' is denied.
```

Is there anything I'm missing? I'm not sure how to debug since it works fine in development mode.

```
public static class Logger
{

    private static string FilePath
    {
        get
        {
            return Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "log.txt");
        }
    }

    public static void Clear()
    {
        if (File.Exists(FilePath))
        {
            File.Delete(FilePath);
        }
    }

    public static void Log(string sLine)
    {
        File.AppendAllLines(FilePath, new string[] { sLine });
    }

    public static void Show()
    {
        if (File.Exists(FilePath))
        {
            Process.Start(FilePath);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The write access to the program files directory requires special permissions and best practice is to use the app data folder to store files created by your application.

[file write permission issue under "Program Files" folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191941/file-write-permission-issue-under-program-files-folder)